# How do I upload to S3 server from EC2 with low cost?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, upload

i have 5072,792,622 files every month to upload on s3 server and it's costing me lot of money as we are using PUT request to upload them to s3 server, is there another method which I can use to upload files to s3. These files cannot be upload as zip, s3 do not support unzip on s3.

Comment: I'd love to know the use case for five billion files per month being created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to consider that S3 is not the right solution for you. Those files must be uploaded individually to S3, so there's no way around the costs you're experiencing.

You can consider one of the lower storage classes, which will help your GB/month costs, but they will not make data ingestion any cheaper.

Comment: Thx for replying, i guess i have to look for alternative of s3 then.